# Can't read my map data

Tags: c++, qt, oop

i have a problem with reading my map data or possibly even writing it in.

the app i'm making is a basic currency converter.

I download the exchange rates from a website, save it into txt file, which i then parse to save the values into a map and use my calculator class to do the conversion.

the downloader class works flawless (i got it of official QT forums) so i wont post it since the problem aint there.

the code: main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMap<QString,double> currency_map;

    downloader d;
    d.Do_download();

    parser p;
    p.read_line(currency_map);

    p.print_map(currency_map);// this line works, and it prints out the map

    MainWindow w(currency_map);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
};
```

parser.cpp 
im pretty sure it works well because the print_map function does its job.

```
void parser::process_line(QString line, QMap<QString, double> &my_map)
{

    QStringList temporary_list;

    for(int i = 0; i< currency_list.size();i++)
        {
        if(line.contains(currency_list.at(i),Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {

            temporary_list=line.split(" ",QString::SkipEmptyParts);

            temporary_list.replaceInStrings(",",".");
            my_map.insert(currency_list.at(i),temporary_list[6].toDouble());
        }
    }

}

int parser::read_line(QMap<QString, double> &my_map)
{

    QFile file("C:/Qt/test/downloaded.txt");

    if(!file.exists())
        {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("There is no such file");
        msgBox.exec();
        return 1;
    }    
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly  | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Error while opening file");
        msgBox.exec();
        return 1;
    }

    QTextStream in_stream(&file);
    QString line=in_stream.readLine();

    while (!line.isNull())
        {
        process_line(line, my_map);
        line = in_stream.readLine();
    }
    return 0;
}

void parser::print_map(QMap<QString, double> &my_map)
{
   QMapIterator<QString, double> i(my_map);
    while(i.hasNext())
        {
        i.next();
        qDebug()<< i.key() << ": " << i.value();
    }   
}
```

now i have a calculator class :

.h

```
class Calculator
{
public:
    explicit Calculator(QMap<QString,double> &currency_map);
    void multiply();
    void getValues(QString strFrom, QString strTo);
    double getTotal();
private:
    double total, firstCurr, secondCurr;
    QMap<QString,double> &map;

};
```

.cpp

```
#include "calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator(QMap<QString,double> &currency_map):map(currency_map)
{
    total = 0;
    firstCurr = 0;
    secondCurr= 0;
}

void Calculator::getValues(QString strFrom, QString strTo)
{
    QMap<QString, double>::iterator i;
    for(i=map.begin();i!=map.end();i++)
        {

            if(!i.key().compare(strFrom))
                firstCurr=i.value();
            if(!i.key().compare(strTo))
                secondCurr = i.value();
    }
        //firstCurr = 2;
        //secondCurr = 3;
}

void Calculator::multiply()
{
    total = firstCurr * secondCurr;
}

double Calculator::getTotal()
{
    return total;
}
```

then i create a Calculator object in my mainWindow class
.h

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QMap<QString,double> &currency_map, QWidget *parent = 0);

        ~MainWindow();


    private slots:
        void on_convert_button_clicked();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        Calculator calc;

    };
```

.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QMap<QString, double> &currency_map, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),calc(currency_map)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_convert_button_clicked()
{
    calc.getValues(ui->from_Combox->currentText(),ui->to_Combox->currentText());
    calc.multiply();
    ui->lcdNumber->display(calc.getTotal());
}
```

but i cant seem to get any values from the map.
the wierd thing also is when i debugg(i use visual studio) its always shows the map as empty, which i cant grasp since the print function works.

any help would be appreciated. thx

Comment: I have a feeling the problem could be when you create the calc instance; could you try declaring calc as a pointer and build it in your MainWindow constructor using the &currency_map parameter, so something like calc = new Calculator(currency_map)

Comment: did, nothing changes.

Comment: Can you try making the map declaration within the Calculator class not be a reference?

Comment: yes, i tried. but the map is "empty" all the time if you ask debugger, so it could be that my data saving methods are bad, which kind of aint possible since i got a functional print method.
right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculator has a member variable which is a *reference* to a `QMap` of currency values.  If the `QMap` it references goes out of scope, then the reference becomes invalid.  Change the declaration of the member variable in your calculator class to this:

```
QMap<QString,double> map;
```

This will copy the map instead of making a reference to it.  I would also put a breakpoint in the calculator constructor and verify that the map still has valid data at that point.

Comment: Ok, i understand the first part.
But the funny part is, if i put a breakpoint in my main after i call p.read_line(currency_map), just before i print out my map
the debugger gives me [key](error), [value] 0
but my print functions prints "AUD" :  5.13678 and 11 more lines of different examples.
and this dazzle's me because i dont know where it gets the data from, IF the debugger says the map is empty

Comment: That is odd.  Next I would try single-stepping through the `for` loop in your `Calculator::getValues` function.  Make sure that the input strings are properly matching up to the key values in the map.  Also, I've never used Visual Studio as an IDE for Qt programs.  I would consider the possibility that the debugger is not grabbing the debug data properly.  Try making a dummy map in your main function and filling it with arbitrary values, then see if the debugger reports its contents properly.